# How to add not equals to in VBA

Tags: vba, if-statement

In visual basic its <> but when i use it in VBA, it gives an error.
I am using VBA in excel:

My command (works for equals)
If ActiveCell.Value = 0 Then

My command (does not work for not equals to)
If ActiveCell.Value <> 0 THen

Comment: What exception message are you receiving? The operator `<>` is valid VBA. My guess is that the problem is that you are testing `=` and `<>` in different areas of your code. Most likely, when you are testing `<>` with `ActiveCell`, the object is `Nothing`, so when you attempt to compare `ActiveCell.Value` to any value in your code, an exception is thrown.

Comment: Please never use the words "does not work". Please explain why. Do you get an error? what is it? Or do you get an unexpected outcome?

Comment: Does `ActiveCell` contain a worksheet error (e.g. `#VALUE!` or  `#DIV/0!`)? If this gives you a *Runtime error 13. Type mismatch.* then you are going to get that whether you are using = or <>. Edit your post to include some details and we should be able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would not advise to anyone to operate on "Active" objects in VBA. It is really tricky.

Try to assign all your Workbooks, Worksheets and Ranges to actual Objects. Like for example:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'good to use it in button code.

Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheet(1)

Dim rng as Range
Set rng = ws.Range("A1")
```

You should not get an error if you make sure that Object you are referring to exists.